# What is the login name of the account logged in with Microsoft ID when connect to Windows 10 remotely or in Remote Desktop Client?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-live-id, windows-10-desktop

When I was coding C# to connect from Mac to a Windows 10 PC I found a failed connection. I tried again with Microsoft Remote Desktop Client and it said authorization failed. The only account on the PC is logged in with a Microsoft ID which was a LIVE ID before(eg. abc@live.com).

I tried

> abc@live.com"

or the full name displayed in account list which is

> A B (abc@live.com)"

or the user name of the account, also name of the user home folder

> abc

None of them is working.

I managed to connect with a local account credential(regular account name with password) but I need to know how to automatically set the account name in application when the user only logged in with a Microsoft ID(with no offline account).

Any comment?

Answer (score 0):

I also required the same mapping from a Windows Service code and did the following:

Enumerated all users using the API `NetUserEnum()` with level 0 to get each username.

For each username called [`NetUserGetInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370654(v=vs.85).aspx) with level 24. It uses the structure [`_USER_INFO_24`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh994455(v=vs.85).aspx) to return its Internet Identity for the username.

If the `usri24_internet_principal_name` member of the structure matched with the given Microsoft Id then we have located the required username.

Note: Level 24 is available in Windows 8 and above. But can be easily used with previous SDK by simply defining the `_USER_INFO_24` structure in the code.

For a code snippet please see my answer at:
[Get the local login name for the given Microsoft Account returned by NetWkstaUserEnum API on Windows 8 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306052/get-the-local-login-name-for-the-given-microsoft-account-returned-by-netwkstause/34391669#34391669)