# Get the local login name for the given Microsoft Account returned by NetWkstaUserEnum API on Windows 8 and above

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, windows-8, microsoft-account

I am using `NetWkstaUserEnum()` to get the local users name and its domain details.

Till Windows 7 it used to return only the login name and it worked fine. From Windows 8 onwards Microsoft Account was added and for this type of account the API started returning the Microsoft Account name instead of the local login name.

For example it returned `username@outlook.com` instead of `usern_0000` which is the actual Windows local login name.

I cannot use `NetUserEnum()` as it does not return the domain name of the user.

So I need to get the local login name for the given Microsoft Account returned by `NetWkstaUserEnum()` API.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to locate a way to get the Windows username for the given Microsoft Account.It uses `NetUserGetInfo()` to get the Microsoft Account name for the given username.

Code Snippet:

```
do
{
    ntStatus    =   NetUserEnum(szSvr, 0, 0, (LPBYTE*)&userInfo0, dwPrefMaxLen, &dwEntriesRead, &dwTotalEntries, &dwResumeHandle);
    if( (ntStatus == NERR_Success) || (ntStatus == ERROR_MORE_DATA) )
    {
        tmpinfo = userInfo0;
        for( i = 0; (i < dwEntriesRead); i++ )
        {
            if(tmpinfo  != NULL)
            {
                ntStatus    =   NetUserGetInfo(szSvr, tmpinfo->usri0_name, 24,(LPBYTE*)&userInfo24);
                if(ntStatus == NERR_Success)
                {
                    CString internetPrincipalName = (LPCWSTR) userInfo24->usri24_internet_principal_name;
                    if(LoginUsrStr.CompareNoCase(internetPrincipalName) == 0)
                    {
                        OutputDebugString("@@@@@@ Account Found @@@@@@");
                        localAccount = (LPCWSTR) tmpinfo->usri0_name;
                        userFound = TRUE;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            tmpinfo++;
        }
    }

    if( userInfo0 != NULL )
    {
        NetApiBufferFree( userInfo0 ) ;
        userInfo0 = NULL ;
    }
    if( userInfo24 != NULL )
    {
        NetApiBufferFree( userInfo24 ) ;
        userInfo24 = NULL ;
    }

} while( userFound == FALSE && ntStatus == ERROR_MORE_DATA ) ;
```